# iBooks on iPhone: pagination algorithm

Tags: iphone, pagination, ibooks

My iBook has a click&jump feature. A simple `location.href.hash="#id";` results in a page-turning effect even if the element in question is already being shown on the screen. So I want to detect if the element in question is already being displayed. My logic to do this works fine on other ereaders and iBooks for iPad, just not iPhone.

In iBooks on the iPhone, it appears that multiple pages into which a file is paginated are organized in left-to-right fashion on the coordinate system. The problem is that if I am on the second page of a file, `getBoundingClientRect` returns an x-coordinate of, say, 250 for an element falling on that second page; so far so good, since the element is indeed one page over to the right from the left side of the page. The problem is that the left coordinate of the window, whether I access it with `window.scrollX`, or `window.pageXOffset`, or `document.body.scrollLeft`, or `document.documentElement.scrollLeft`, is always returned as zero, whereas it should be a positive number indicating that the screen is displaying a portion of the page scrolled to the right. Since it is zero, it appears that the element in question is *not* visible (off to the right), and I need to set `location.href`, which causes the undesirable page-turning effect.

I have a vague suspicion that they may be playing with CSS transforms which are not reflected in the results of the `getBoundingClientRect` call. The Mozilla docs explicitly say that their implementation of `getBoundingClientRect` *does* take into account transforms, but I am not sure if this is the case with webkit, and if not, how to determine the transform being applied to an element via some ancestor.

This question ends up being about iBooks/iPhone internals, but I wonder if there is any way of determining the actual correct left scrolling coordinate when on the second and succeeding pages of a file.